# MapRouteFinder.GetDrivingRouteFromWaypointsAsync(waypoints) stays in endless loop and doesn´t return

Tags: c#, uwp, bing-maps

I have a list with `2 Geopoints` in it. I´d like to have a route from `waypoint[0]` to `waypoint[1]`.

i call the async function `MapRouteFinder.GetDrivingRouteFromWaypointsAsync(waypoints);`

in the most cases it returns a route perfectly. But with some specific coordinates it doesn´t return. 
Is there a knwon issue with the framework?

```
mapRouteFinderResult = await MapRouteFinder.GetDrivingRouteFromWaypointsAsync(waypoints);
```

i expected an `mapRouteFinderResult` with the status success or the status No point found or sth else. but not a non returning Task

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and see if you get a response and the status code (like 200 OK).  Most likely it is not getting back 200 OK or response is timing out.

Comment: Hi, please provide the `specific coordinates` you mentioned, which will help me debug this problem better.

Comment: These are for example 48.53013 , 12.11839; 48.53038 , 12.11818; 48.529030 , 12.116215
These 3 fail in every combination.

Comment: Hi, Sorry, I can't reproduce your question. I set the first number to `Latitude` and the second to `Longitude`, like `new BasicGeoposition { Latitude = 48.53013, Longitude = 12.11839 }` I put the three coordinates you gave in an array and called it, it returns normally. path. When I reversed the coordinates, I got the result of `NoRouteFound` (at `mapRouteFinderResult.Status`). But in any case, I got the result. Can you provide a complete recurring step?